# The unit group of $\mathbb{Q}[x, y]/(x^2+y^2+1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra

During some calculations, I encountered with the problem of calculating the unit group of the $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra $\mathbb{Q}[x, y]/(x^2+y^2+1)$. I believe it is the unit group of the field of rational numbers, but I can't find any good way of proving this. Any suggestion will certainly be welcomed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R=\mathbb Q[x,y]/(x^2+y^2+1)$. Remark that

$$R\otimes \mathbb Q(i) = \mathbb Q(i)[x,y]/(x^2+y^2+1) = \mathbb Q(i)[x,y]/((x+iy)(x-iy)+1),$$ so $R\otimes \mathbb Q(i)$ is isomorphic over $\mathbb Q(i)$ to $\mathbb Q(i)[u,v]/(uv+1)$, which is itself isomorphic to $\mathbb Q(i)[s,t]/(st-1)$ by $s\mapsto u, t \mapsto -v$. So $R\otimes \mathbb Q(i)$ is $\mathbb Q(i)[s,s^{-1}]$, whose unit group is $\mathbb Q(i)^\times \times s^\mathbb Z$. Now, if $\alpha \in R$ is a unit, then it is still a unit in $R\otimes \mathbb Q(i)$, hence it lies in $\mathbb Q(i)^\times \times s^\mathbb Z$. Hence $\alpha = c s^k$ for some $c \in \mathbb Q(i)$ and for $s = x+iy$. Comparing the coefficient of $x$ on both sides of $\alpha = c s^k$ shows that we must have $c \in \mathbb Q$, and then comparing the coefficient of $y$ on both sides shows that we must have $k=0$, hence $\alpha = c \in \mathbb Q^\times$.

Comment: What is this supposed to mean: "is isomorphic over $\mathbb Q(i)$"?

Comment: @user26857 As a $\mathbb Q(i)$-algebra.

Comment: This seems great! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

A direct approach.

Let $R=\mathbb Q[Y]$, and $p=Y^2+1$. Your ring is $R[X]/(X^2+p)$, and its elements are of the form $ax+b$ with $a,b\in R$. (Here $x$ denotes the residue class of $X$ modulo the ideal $(X^2+p)$.)

Suppose $ax+b$ is invertible. Then there are $c,d\in R$ such that $(ax+b)(cx+d)=1$, that is $(ad+bc)x+bd-pac=1$. (Recall that $x^2=-p$.) It follows $ad+bc=0$ and $bd-pac=1$. This leads to $c=-a(d^2+pc^2)$ and $d=b(d^2+pc^2)$ which gives $(b^2+pa^2)(d^2+pc^2)=1$. Thus $b^2+pa^2$ is invertible in $R$, so $\deg(b^2+pa^2)=0$. In particular, $\deg b=\deg a+1$ and by looking now at the coefficients of the monomials of highest degree in $a$ and $b$ we conclude that the sum of their squares is zero, unless $a=0$. (This proof works as well for $\mathbb R$ instead of $\mathbb Q$.)

Comment: The equation $(b^2+pa^2)(d^2+pc^2)=1$ may sound like a norm $1$ criterion for invertibility. Well, we can actually define such a "norm" on $R[X]/(X^2+p)$.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer and the comment are inspiring.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R=\mathbb Q[x,y]/(x^2+y^2+1)$ and $u=p_1(x)+p_2(x)y\in R^{*}$ be a unit. Then, $\exists v=q_1(x)+q_2(x)y\in R$ such that $uv=1.$ After multiplication, we get
$$p_1(x)q_1(x)-p_2(x)q_2(x)(x^2+1)=1\tag1$$
and
$$p_1(x)q_2(x)=q_1(x)p_2(x)\tag2$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we can deduce that $q_1(x)=N(v)p_1(x)$ and $q_2(x)=N(v)p_2(x)$ where $N(v)=q_1^2(x)-q_2^2(x)(x^2+1).$ In other words, $v=N(v)u$. Similarly, we can deduce that $u=N(u)v$ where $N(u)=p_1^2(x)-p_2^2(x)(x^2+1)$. Hence, we can get $N(u)N(v)=1.$ From this we deduce that $N(v)=\frac{1}{a}\neq 0$ is a non-zero constant. Now, $v=\frac1au$ and $u^2=a$ which implies that $p_2(x)=0$ and $u=p_1(x)=\pm\sqrt{a}$.

Conclusion: $R^*=\Bbb Q^{*}.$

Comment: Why do you introduce $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{Q}$? These are totally unnecessary

Comment: @math54321 You are right. Maybe I thought monic polynomials.